# Get hash value of a pytorch architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, hash, pytorch

I would like to automatically check whether a certain architecture has already been trained on a task. My thought is: If I can get a hash value of the architecture and store this value in a .json file, then I can check whether it has already been trained by checking whether the architecture's hash value is in the .json file.

However, I'm not exactly sure what to hash: If I hash the module object, then it will be different each time I run the program since it'll have a different id, because it's in a different memory location. Also, different random initializations will probably cause a different hash value.

Is there a way I can get a hash value that will be the same so long as the module consists of the same layers with the same dimensions?

Comment: Do you want to also *"include"* the forward definition of your model in that hash?

Comment: ideally yes. If that is significantly harder, I'd still like to have the hash that doesn't include it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into object hashing in Python?

Comment: I've looked into object hashing, and it gives different values for two instances of the same Module, even if they have the same architecture.

Comment: You most likely need to hash the architecture, not an instance of it. Two trained networks are unlikely to have exactly the same weights (up to floating point precision), so object hashing is not gonna work I think

Comment: Are you suggesting to hash the class? Unfortunately this also gives a different hash value each time I run it. Probably because the memory location is different each time, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think hashing the string representation of the model might be a solution to your problem.

```
hash(str(model))
```